# How to object values in specified manner from json having different nesting

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html

i wanted to construct `array` from `json` into specified manner

**here is my json**

```
var data = {
    "first": {
        "dial": {
            "ss": true,
            "tt": false
        },
        "report": {
            "rr": true,
            "mm": false
        },
        "media": {
            "media": false,
        }
    },
    "second": {
        "media": {
        },
        "order": {
            "cg_counter": true,
            "sub_vertical": false
        },
        "rrt":{
           "mtnl":{
              "gistn":12344,
              "qt":"testing",
           }
        }
    }
};
```

**I'm expecting my output (below one):**

> **first:**
>       dial: ss , tt
>
> report: rr , mm
>
> media: media
>
> **second:**
>      media:
>
> order: cg_counter , sub_vertical
>
> rrt:   mtnl : gistn , qt

i have tried coding like below one(i don't understand how many level of nesting i have to do).

```
for(var key in data)
{

     console.log(key.toUpperCase() + ' : ');

    if(typeof data[key] == 'object'){

         for(anotherKey in data[key]){
             console.log(data[key][anotherKey]);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: be very careful with typeof because typeof null === 'object', otherwise you will need some recursive function to solve this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
var data = {
    "first": {
        "dial": {
            "ss": true,
            "tt": false
        },
        "report": {
            "rr": true,
            "mm": false
        },
        "media": {
            "media": false,
        }
    },
    "second": {
        "media": {
        },
        "order": {
            "cg_counter": true,
            "sub_vertical": false
        },
        "rrt":{
           "mtnl":{
              "gistn":12344,
              "qt":"testing",
           }
        }
    }
};

function get_all_data(_data){
   for(var key in _data){
     if (typeof _data[key] == "object" && _data[key] !== null){
          console.log(key +' => '+ 'object restart function!');
          get_all_data(_data[key]);
     }else{
          console.log(' '+key + ' => ' + _data[key]);
     }
   }
}

get_all_data(data);
```